# c# get bits from int as int

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I need to get 4 ints from a integer with the following format

```
    int1 14 bits
    int2 14 bits
    int3 3 bits
    int4 1 bit
```

I've found a lot of articles for reading individual bits from an int but I can't find anything on reading multiple values from a single integer so and help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think an example with an initial value and the expected result would be in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's *assume* your 32-bit int is arranged bit-wise as follows, and your target variables are X, Y, Z and W.

```
31                                0 # bit index
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYYY ZZZ W # arrangement
......14...... ......14...... .3. 1 # bits per variable
............18 .............4 ..1 0 # required right-shift
```

To get at `X`, you would shift your integer right by 18 bits, then mask it by `((1<<14)-1)` (that is 0x3FFF), etc.:

```
x = (i >> 18) & 0x3FFF
y = (i >> 4) & 0x3FFF
z = (i >> 1) & 7 # ((1<<3)-1) = 7
w = i & 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Asuming it is from left to right

```
int int1 = x >> 18;
int int2 = (x >> 4) & 0x3fff;
int int3 = (x >> 1) & 7;
int int4 = x & 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use bitwise and to get this:

```
int source = somevalue;

int int1 = 16383&somevalue;
int int2 = 268419072&somevalue;
int int3 = 1879048192&somevalue;
```